# String is effected by `downcase!` operation

Tags: ruby, string, immutability

I'm trying to read a file line by line and process the data. This is users table data. I'm extracting `account_id` and `user_id` and then trying to downcast `user_id` while saving the original `user_id`. I have the following code:

```
# account_id | user_id | address | user_name |  passwordDigest
line = "g_1e035sadas-035e-45ba-9a1f-40d20000 |    MyUser999 | Alabama | Felix The Cat | 12Yoiqbdz/jCCDASD2kA8D4M5V9pZ3KyWiaj |  null |        null |" 

raw_line = line.split('|')
# => ["g_1e035sadas-035e-45ba-9a1f-40d20000 ", "    MyUser999 ", " Alabama ", " Felix The Cat ", " 12Yoiqbdz/jCCDASD2kA8D4M5V9pZ3KyWiaj ", "  null ", "        null "]

filtered_raw_line = raw_line.take(2)
# => ["g_1e035sadas-035e-45ba-9a1f-40d20000 ", "    MyUser999 "]

items = filtered_raw_line.collect{|x| x.strip || x }
# => ["g_1e035sadas-035e-45ba-9a1f-40d20000", "MyUser999"] 

original_user_id = items[-1]
# => "MyUser999"

items[-1].downcase!
# => "myuser999"

original_user_id
# => "myuser999"
```

I can't figure out why `original_user_id` changes after performing `downcase!` operation on one of the array cells.

Comment: Because `original_user_id = items2[-1]` doesn't create a copy of the string. If you want to preserve the original string, you should not change it. Assigning a new string via `items2[-1] = items2[-1].downcase` would work.

Comment: This `original_user_id = items2[-1]` creates a reference and does not copy value.

Comment: My bad . it should have been items[-1].downcase! and not items2[-1].downcase!

Comment: BTW, the `|| x` in `x.strip || x` is extraneous, because `String#strip` never returns `nil` or `false`.

Comment: You haven't selected an answer. We're none of them satisfactory?

Answer (score 2):

> I probably missing some OOP fundamental programming concept

There are two fundamental and distinct operations:

1. Assigning an object to a variable
2. Sending a message to an object

And it only works that way, i.e. only objects can be assigned<sup>1</sup>, only variables can be assigned-to<sup>2</sup> and messages can only be sent to objects<sup>3</sup>.

That being said, let's look at your code:

```
items[-1]
```

fetches the last object from the array and returns it: the string `"MyUser999"`.

```
original_user_id = items[-1]
```

assigns that object to the variable `original_user_id`.

Both, `items[-1]` and `original_user_id` now refer to the same object.

```
items[-1].downcase!
```

fetches the last object and sends it a `downcase!` message. Upon receiving this message, the string downcases all of its characters.

At this point, `items[-1]` and `original_user_id` still refer to the same object, i.e. the (now downcased) string `"myuser999"`.

```
original_user_id #=> "myuser999"
```

Just as expected.

---

<sup>1</sup> Although you can write `my_var = my_other_var`, this doesn't assign the *variable* `my_other_var` to `my_var`, but the *object* that is assigned to `my_other_var`.

<sup>2</sup> Ruby does have [assignment methods](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/doc/syntax/assignment_rdoc.html#label-Assignment+Methods), but they are merely syntactic sugar for sending messages, i.e. `hash.default = 123` is equivalent to `hash.default=(123)` or `hash.send(:default=, 123)`

<sup>3</sup> `my_var.foo` doesn't send the message `foo` to the *variable* `my_var`, but to the *object* that is assigned to `my_var`. Likewise `array[0].foo` doesn't send the message `foo` to an array "cell", but to the object at index 0.

Answer (score 0):

You might do

```
original_user_id = items2[-1].dup
```

`object#dup` create a duplicate of the object instead use the same reference

Answer (score 0):

You need to create duplicate of the object or copy the value, bcs `downcase!` modify the original string and you just create refference to object, not duplicated value. So you can easily do this:

```
original_user_id = items[-1]

items[-1] = items[-1].downcase

original_user_id 
# => MyUser999
```

or you can modify you code

```
items = line.split('|').take(2).map{|s| s.strip}
original_user_id = items[-1]
#=> MyUser999
items[-1] = items[-1].downcase
#=> myuser999
original_user_id 
#=> MyUser999
```